# SQL Update Query Error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This worked before but now it isn't working and I'm very confused. I reviewed the whole thing and it all looks fine but maybe somebody more advanced can spot something?

Here's the script:

```
UPDATE Orders SET Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped',Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID = null
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus in ('Pending','Processing') 
AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
AND Orders.ShipDate < dateadd(day, -60, convert(char(10), getdate(), 101))
AND Orders.Shipped = Y
```

All I'm getting is an Error, no explanation. Can somebody spot an error, I'm sure it's obvious I'm just too new to SQL to identify it. Thanks

Comment: your `Orders.Shipped = Y` should be `Orders.Shipped = 'Y'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what the error you're getting is, but you need to have Y in quotes.

```
UPDATE Orders SET Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped',Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID = null
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus in ('Pending','Processing') 
AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
AND Orders.ShipDate < dateadd(day, -60, convert(char(10), getdate(), 101))
AND Orders.Shipped = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 2):

Y in the last row must be in ''

```
UPDATE Orders SET Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped',Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID = null
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus in ('Pending','Processing') 
AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
AND Orders.ShipDate < dateadd(day, -60, convert(char(10), getdate(), 101))
AND Orders.Shipped = 'Y'
```

Or it would be good if you post the error too

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Orders SET Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped',Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID = null
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus in ('Pending','Processing') 
AND Orders.PaymentAmount = Orders.Total_Payment_Received
AND Orders.ShipDate < dateadd(day, -60, convert(char(10), getdate(), 101))
AND Orders.Shipped = 'Y'